# Docker and pip requirements

Tags: python, docker

I want to maintain the development environment for a python application that needs dependencies installed with `pip`.

I plan to have the source code (including `requirements.txt`) pulled from a git repo into a host folder which is mounted as a docker volume.

Is there a docker pattern to keep the libraries updated and yet avoid the expensive `pip install -r requirements.txt` with every `git pull`?

Comment: So what kind of solution are you looking for? Questions asking for "recommendations" or "best practices" are often closed as "too broad".

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Edited my question; I hope it's less broad now.

Comment: You'll mostly have to install your Python dependencies in your Docker container and keep it aside as an image. Every time you pull your repo, also pull a latest (or whatever is relevant) Docker image and mount onto a container built with the same image. You'll have to manually keep updating the container as and when dependencies are updated. You might benefit by keeping that in your build process so that it builds an image for every push.

Answer (score 0):

The way to avoid installing every time is to do the `pip install` in a separate `RUN` instruction before you pull the whole repo. To do that you'll need another way to get your `requirements.txt` into the container - maybe with `ADD`, specifying the full remote URL:

```
ADD https://raw.githubusercontent.com/etc/requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

When you `docker build` this, if the contents of `requirements.txt` hasn't changed then the cached layer with all the installed dependencies will be used. If the requirements file has changed, then the install will run again.

If you go with this, you'll want specific versions in your requirements file, and you'll have to manually update it for version bumps.

Comment: But wouldn't this approach still require that I `docker build` the image on my local machine after every `git pull`, which would then `pip install`, and make me wait for 10-15 minutes before I can continue work? Of course, if `requirements.txt` didn't change, the image will remain unchanged, saving disk space; but I was also hoping to avoid the wait time after `git pull`.